# Mongo DB - export in JSON extended mode

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to know if there is any command or tool to export mongo collections in JSON extended mode instead of strict mode which is the default mode.

Any suggestion will be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [strict mode export](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) supported by [`mongoexport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) and [`mongoimport`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) *is* extended JSON:

> Strict mode representations of BSON types conform to the JSON RFC. Any JSON parser can parse these strict mode representations as key/value pairs; however, only the MongoDB’s internal JSON parser also recognizes the type information conveyed by the format.

There is also a looser representation for the `mongo` shell which is JSON-like, but allows syntax which is not valid JSON. For example, the shell syntax allows unquoted string values which represent helper functions (such as `ISODate()`) for extended data types.

Extended JSON:

```
{
   "_id":{
       "$oid":"55d39fac2ba0663a655bee54"
   },
   "day":{
        "$date":"2015-08-18T21:12:12.945Z"
   }
}
```

`mongo` shell syntax (JSON-like):

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("55d39fac2ba0663a655bee54"),
  "day": ISODate("2015-08-18T21:12:12.945Z")
}
```

#### Exporting from the `mongo` shell

If you really want to export a collection in `mongo` shell syntax, you can pipe the output to a file.

This format will only be understood by the `mongo` shell, and you will likely run into limitations if you are trying to print a large collection:

```
mongo server:port/dbname --eval "printjson(db.collection.find().toArray())"
```

The standard command line tools for importing/exporting collections as JSON are `mongoimport` and `mongoexport`. These generally aren't suitable for database backups -- see the MongoDB manual for supported [Backup and Recovery tutorials](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backup/).

Comment: This command works fine. is there any way to print the result to a file? Thank you!

Comment: @AlexGuerreiro Yes, just redirect the output in your terminal session, eg: `mongo server:port/dbname --quiet --eval "printjson(db.collection.find().toArray())" > output.json`. Note: I added "--quiet" which will suppress any connection messages. This option is probably not needed if you have a recent (3.x) version of `mongo`, but some older shell versions would print unwanted output to stdout.