# Force mongodb to output strict JSON

Tags: json, mongodb, shell, bson

I want to consume the raw output of some MongoDB commands in other programs that speak JSON. When I run commands in the mongo shell, they represent [Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/), fields in "shell mode", with special fields like `NumberLong` , `Date`, and `Timestamp`. I see references in the documentation to "strict mode", but I see no way to turn it on for the shell, or a way to run commands like `db.serverStatus()` in things that *do* output strict JSON, like `mongodump`. How can I force Mongo to output standards-compliant JSON?

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5761053/is-there-a-way-to-run-mongodb-shell-or-tojson-method-in-strict-json-mode) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32079600/mongo-db-export-in-json-extended-mode) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867538/how-can-i-use-python-to-transform-mongodbs-bsondump-into-json) on this topic, but I don't find any of their answers particularly satisfactory.

Comment: You have this the wrong way around. The shell uses "strict" syntax which is `{ "a": NumberLong(1) }` etc.And "Extended JSON" which is not supported by the shell at all, is used by tools like `mongoexport` which does `"a":{"$numberLong":"1"}}` which is parsable JSON form. `mongodump` just dumps BSON datafiles.

Comment: You are incorrect. The [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/#numberlong) clearly shows that the "strict mode" representation of the NumberLong type is `{ "$numberLong": "<number>" }`, while the "shell mode" representation is `NumberLong( "<number>" )`. I can edit the question to clarify the difference between "extended JSON" and "shell mode".

Comment: Like I said. You have this completely in reverse. Extened JSON is what you are calling "strict".

Comment: The semantics don't really change the question or the answer, but FWIW, the previously linked documentation specifies that both "shell mode" and "strict mode" are extensions on JSON, so "Extended JSON" includes both. If there's other documentation that indicates otherwise, I'd be interested to see it.

Comment: Blakes Seven please read http://docs.mongoing.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json.html
strict mode  -> { "$oid": "<id>" }
shell mode -> ObjectId( "<id>" )
strict = standard Json

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The MongoDB shell speaks Javascript, so the answer is simple: use `JSON.stringify()`. If your command is `db.serverStatus()`, then you can simply do this:

```
JSON.stringify(db.serverStatus())
```

This won't output the proper "strict mode" representation of each of the fields (`{ "floatApprox": <number> }` instead of `{ "$numberLong": "<number>" }`), but if what you care about is getting standards-compliant JSON out, this'll do the trick.

Comment: And this is false as well. as `JSON.stringify({ "a": NumberLong(1) })` comes out as `{"a":{"floatApprox":1}}` which is totally not the [Extended JSON](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format. I think before you go for any more self answers you should research the material a bit more.

Comment: The crux of the question is how to get the shell to spit out something that can be parsed by a standards-compliant JSON parser. This accomplishes that goal. I will edit the answer to clarify that though.

Comment: Can you suggest an improvement?

Comment: Would be great if we also got an answer to "Force mongodb to output Extended JSON"... but that is not what you are asking

Comment: You rock. You made my day! Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks for this, php cannot decode printjsononeline output.  JSON.stringify works very nicely and is actual valid JSON. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

I have not found a way to do this in the mongo shell, but as a workaround, `mongoexport` can run queries and its output uses strict mode and can be piped into other commands that expect JSON input (such as `json_pp` or `jq`).  For example, suppose you have the following mongo shell command to run a query, and you want to create a pipeline using that data:

```
db.myItemsCollection.find({creationDate: {$gte: ISODate("2016-09-29")}}).pretty()
```

Convert that mongo shell command into this shell command, piping for the sake of example to `json_pp:

```
mongoexport --jsonArray -d myDbName -c myItemsCollection -q '{"creationDate": {"$gte": {"$date": "2016-09-29T00:00Z"}}}' | json_pp
```

You will need to convert the query into strict mode format, and pass the database name and collection name as arguments, as well as quote properly for your shell, as shown here.

Comment: Did not know about this! I only wish it supported aggregations.

Answer (score 4):

In case of findOne

```
JSON.stringify(db.Bill.findOne({'a': '123'}))
```

In case of a cursor

```
db.Bill.find({'a': '123'}).forEach(r=>print(JSON.stringify(r)))
```

or

```
print('[') + db.Bill.find().limit(2).forEach(r=>print(JSON.stringify(r) + ',')) + print(']')
```

will output

```
[{a:123},{a:234},]
```

> the last one will have a ',' after the last item...remove it

Answer (score 1):

To build on the answer from @jbyler, you can strip out the numberLongs using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) after you get your data - that is if you're using linux.

```
mongoexport --jsonArray -d dbName -c collection -q '{fieldName: {$regex: ".*turkey.*"}}' | sed -r 's/\{ "[$]numberLong" : "([0-9]+)" }/"\1"/g' | json_pp
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: This will transform a given document, but will not work on a list of documents. Changed `find` to `findOne`.

Adding

```
.forEach(function(results){results._id=results._id.toString();printjson(results)})`
```

to a `findOne()` will output valid JSON.

Example:

```
db
  .users
  .findOne()
  .forEach(function (results) {
    results._id = results._id.toString();
    printjson(results)
  })
```

Source: https://www.mydbaworld.com/mongodb-shell-output-valid-json/

Comment: not general enough.  I have a large doc, it's difficult to process each field on my own.