# Jq cannot parse MongoDB output document

Tags: json, mongodb, jq

Jq is a wonderfull tool to deals with JS document in bash. But I can't use to parse some MongoDB output documents due to function like added by Mongodb.
Example of MongoDB Json return:

```
{
    "_id" : "example",
    "version" : 23,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "192.168.0.1:27017",
            "slaveDelay" : NumberLong(0),   <---- Here jq failed to parse this line
            "votes" : 1
        }
]}
```

The error given by jq is:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 15, column 32
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I know I am a little too late here but Mongo shell has built-in JavaScript support. So you can use `JSON.stringify`.

For the specific example above, you can use below

`mongo --quiet --eval "JSON.stringify(rs.config())"`

Comment: Woow. Many thank's for this. I think it is a best answer than the workaround given below.

Answer (score 7):

A workaround that could be sufficient for certain use is to transform the output of the mongo shell command. I use this pattern for a workaround:

```
mongo --quiet --eval "rs.config()" | sed -e 's/: [a-zA-Z]*(\(.*\))/: "\1"/' | jq '.'
```

It removes all functions call after the ':' and keep only the value.

Comment: that nice workaround!

Comment: I found I got better luck with this sed expression: `sed -e 's/: [a-zA-Z]*(\([^\)]*\))/: \1/g'`. Just thought I'd share.

Answer (score 5):

this is caused because mongo uses BSON in the backend [see this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/)

using mongoexport with `json` option will allow to generate clean json files:

```
 "CreatedDate":{"$date":"2016-08-13T01:01:20.833Z"}
```

instead of:

```
 "CreatedDate" : ISODate("2016-08-13T01:01:20.833Z"),
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer but I need this for mongo shell command output and not in data export. For instance, I need to parse the result of the "rs.config()" which show the ReplicatSet configuration. The exact I would like to parse is the following: mongo --eval "rs.config()"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097209/force-mongodb-to-output-strict-json. I ran into the exact same issue!