# Does JSON.parse support parsing string without double quote

Tags: javascript

I have below json data. The problem is on the last field `"totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(2)`. The `NumberLong(2)` is not quoted. When I run `JSON.parse` I got an exception about this field. Is there a way for `JSON.parse` to ignore double quote? I don't want to pre-parse the string by myself so I am looking for a way to handle this automatically for me.

```
{
  "executionStages" : {
    "stage" : "SINGLE_SHARD",
    "nReturned" : 10000,
    "executionTimeMillis" : 3,
    "totalKeysExamined" : 0,
    "totalDocsExamined" : 10000,
    "totalChildMillis" : NumberLong(2)
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it is invalid json.  If you want to pass a method with a parameter, you can make them two separate fields and then do something like window[data.totalChildMethod].call(data.totalChildMillis);

Comment: Who produced above JSON? You or third party?

Comment: Mongodb can produce outputs like `NumberLong(2)`

Comment: @engineforce The mongo shell produced the JSON. I send an explain command to mongo shell and got that output from standard stream.

Comment: [Force mongodb to output strict JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32097209/force-mongodb-to-output-strict-json) may solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid json, so `JSON.parse` will rightfully fail. It seems you can make it a valid json by doing

```
var jsonString = rawString.replace(/NumberLong\((\d*)\)/g, "$1")
```

and then

```
JSON.parse(jsonString)
```

If `NumberLong` is coming from Mongo, you probably can get it to output a valid json directly